# Como posso passar uma variável para o comando 7za como parâmetro no PowerShell?

Tags: cmd, powershell

Antes de tudo estou usando o 7za sistema de compactação de arquivos para linha de comando, estou rodando o Windows 10.
No seguinte comando:

```
$nomeArq ="Nome Aleatorio.zip"
7za a -tzip $nomeArq "Minhas coisas"
```

A execução dele deu errado infelizmente, ai tentei renomear (tentei usar o Rename-Item do power Shell para renomear e também da erro) após a compactação mas também da erro
A questão é: **como se usa variáveis do power shell nos comandos?**
o comando:

```
echo $nomeArq
```

Funciona corretamente

Answer (score -2):

Quando executar comandos "DOS", certifique-se de passar aspas nos parâmetros

7za a -tzip $nomeArq "Minhas coisas"

Será entendido como

7za a -tzip Nome Aleatorio.zip "Minhas coisas"

Outra questão importante. Sempre trabalhe com caminhos absolutos quando tratar arquivos. Muitos comandos podem não funcionar sem caminho ou com caminho relativo.

Para funcionar, mude:

$nomeArq ='"C:\XXX\YYY\Nome Aleatorio.zip"'